# Regular expression in Excel VBA to perform exact match

Tags: excel, regex, vba, search, vba6

So, I am taking the text from a Cell in excel and then searching for a particular phrase in that text. Now, I need to return true only if it is an exact word match.
For e.g. if the text is "The Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog" and I am searching for "Qui" it should return false, but if I search for "Quick", it should return true.
Similarly, "brown Quick" should return false and "Quick brown" should return true.

So, I tried this using regular expressions in VBA and came up with

```
 With regex
    .Pattern = " *" & search & " *"
 End With
```

Using this code I am not able to generate the desired output. I need to check if the character before the search phrase is either a space or nothing and the character at the end of the search phrase is also either a space or nothing. Kindly help me with it.

Comment: You can also just use `Like` operator, e.g.: `Debug.Print str Like "* " & search Or str Like search & " *" Or str Like "* " & search & " *"` where `str` is the string to be evaluated.

Comment: I tried this `Debug.Print (text Like "* " & search & " *")` it is failing for search phrases that are at the beginning or at the end of the text to be evaluated.

Comment: That depends on what you used as `text` variable. If I was you I would concatenate a leading and trailing space while declaring the variable. In such case the `Like` will perform just as expected. That means you can also get rid of all the `Or` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```vb
Public Function TestRegex(str As String)
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    With RegEx
        .Pattern = "\b" & str & "\b"
        .Global = True
    End With
    
    TestRegex = RegEx.Test("The Quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
End Function
```

Results:

```vb
?TestRegex("Qui")
False

?TestRegex("Quick")
True

?TestRegex("brown Quick")
False

?TestRegex("Quick brown")
True
```

By using word boundary (`\b`), you can specify in the regex pattern that you are searching for complete word(s).

Comment: `\b` will do just fine, see [this](https://regex101.com/r/FuMIk4/2). The linked answer in your explaination also shows that there is no difference and you can drop the ancors.

Comment: Hi, it may behave differently on different versions of Excel. Please follow the link for more information.

Comment: @sbgib That answer is not correct. `\bThis` will always match `This` in `This is it`, just tested in VBA.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, done. The original question originates from a typo I'm sure.

Comment: Ok, I've simplified the answer. I have no preference about it, I simply tried to make sure it worked for the OP with an unknown Excel version.